# Django REST Framework: How to create/handle auth_token for existing and new users?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Currently working on a web-app that I'm implementing an API for. This API will be consumed by an iOS application.

Django REST Framekwork provides a convenince view to create tokens for users, providing the username+password are included in the headers:

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token)
]
```

Assumption is users will be registering and logging in from both web and app. What's the best way to handle this? My biggest quibble is with existing users that will be logging in from the iOS app (they already have an account, but don't have an auth token). My current plan is this:

1. Create auth tokens for all *existing* users.
2. Integrate token creation upon registration so we an cover future cases.

This way I can cover all cases. But is there a better approach?

Comment: What you described looks good. You also need to somehow make the app obtain the token for all existing users. Assuming you're not storing the credentials within the app (and you shouldn't, otherwise there would be no need for tokens) you either need to force reauthentication or provide a grace period in which the previous auth method is still honored.

Comment: @TomaszZieliński - I had planned to store the token in keychain, which is supposed to be secure. Is this a bad idea? Can you elaborate on what you mean “make the app *obtain* tokens for all users”?

Comment: Assuming that you're adding token-based authentication to an existing system system (i.e. the app & the backend) then the app must have authenticated to the backend in some other way? If so, then users currently using the app don't have the authentication tokens stored in their apps. And they need them going forward. So you need to somehow make the app obtain the tokens.

Comment: Oh, yes. I thought I would just authenticate with user + password - if those are correct, check whether token already exists, if not - create and return it to the app, otherwise - just return it. Sounds good?

Comment: As for using the keychain - I'm no mobile app expert but it sounds perfect. What I meant was that from the security perspective you shouldn't store usernames & passwords--only the tokens.

Comment: Yes, that sounds good to me. But just to make sure we're on the same page--you will force reauthentication in the app, for the existing users, to obtain the tokens?

Comment: Yes. The app doesn’t exist yet :)

Comment: Haha, okay, my bad then :)